# override condition in Spring QuerydslPredicate

Tags: spring, predicate, querydsl

I'm using QuerydslPredicate (Spring 4.2.5, Spring Boot 1.3.3, querydsl-core 3.7.0) to create a search web service.
My `Ticket` entity has properties like `name`, `description`, etc.
I want a strict equality on the `name` field, but a "contains" comparison on the `description`.

The web service

```
public Page<Ticket> findAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Ticket.class) Predicate predicate, String description) {
  BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder(predicate);
  if (isNotEmpty(description)) {
      builder.and(QTicket.ticket.description.containsIgnoreCase(description));
  }
  return ticketService.findAll(builder, pageable);
}
```

Problem: when I query my web service like that: `http...?description=foo`, two comparisons are generated for the `description` (I started a debugger and looked at the generated BooleanBuilder). The pseudo-code looks like that: "description = foo AND description contains foo".
I'd like to keep the "contains" comparison only.

I found a workaround: I simply renamed web service's parameter `description` to `descriptionFragment`. This way, I can call `http...?descriptionFragment=foo`.

```
public Page<Ticket> findAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Ticket.class) Predicate predicate, String descriptionFragment) {
  BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder(predicate);
  if (isNotEmpty(descriptionFragment)) {
      builder.and(QTicket.ticket.description.containsIgnoreCase(descriptionFragment));
  }
  return ticketService.findAll(builder, pageable);
}
```

Question: I'd like to avoid this workaround. Is there a way to override default equality on the `description` field?

Comment: Please answer your question in an actual answer, to increase visibility for SO readers (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: my TicketRepository should extends QuerydslBinderCustomizer

```
@Override
default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QTicket qTicket) {
    bindings.bind(qTicket.description).first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
}
```